# Increment value in a MySql query using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Why this code is not working (the value of $artInfo2['phoneState'] is 1):

```
 if($artInfo2['phoneState']==1)
   {
        $bdd->prepare("UPDATE `articulos` SET `telVisto` = `telVisto` + 1 WHERE `ID` ='".$_GET['id']."' ");

        $verPorTodos=$salerInfo2['phone'];
   }
```

I'm using a PDO conection that works good because it works good with other queries. Here is my data base conection **that I use on te top of my page**:

```
$pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lacajota', 'root', '', $pdo_options);
```

And yes I want to update ***telVisto*** incrementing 1 for each time the code is run.

Thank you

Comment: first do some error handling: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php then come back.

Comment: Be more specific about the problem. "it doesn't work" is vague. What happens exactly?

Comment: @BeetleJuice I have no error here the value just dont increase

Comment: Do you know there is no error (have you checked?) or do you assume there is no error because the rest of the code runs without warning? Show more of your PHP script. The lines before and after the query execution.

Comment: @user3791775 I have no error :(

Comment: @BeetleJuice No... I always use the error logs and It looks clean

Comment: Again, please show more of your PHP script. The lines before and after the query execution. What you've shown shouldn't cause any change in the DB because you never run the query. So there is no problem so far.

Comment: Sure I will update my question Thank you! @BeetleJuice

Comment: @BeetleJuice I think that it dont solve anything :(

Comment: I don't see you executing that query.

Comment: When we want to help and we ask for info, please consider giving it so we can provide the help (of course change private info). As you can see, it turns out that your code was missing one key step, and that would have been obvious to us sooner if you had provided the lines around the query execution as I asked.  Glad you have a solution though. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Sanitize your input. Never concatenate a query with `$_GET['something']`, because I can delete your whole database like that.
Step 2: Handle errors properly.
Step 3: `prepare()` doesn't execute the query. It returns a Prepared Statement. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php You still need to execute it.

```
$stmt = $bdd->prepare("UPDATE `articulos` SET `telVisto` = `telVisto` + 1 WHERE `ID` =:id ");
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));
```

Step 4. If nothing works, can you check if you even have a row to update? Does the query

```
SELECT * FROM `articulos` WHERE `ID` = (insert your ID here manually)
```

return anything? Maybe the problem is that you don't work with the correct data?

Comment: Hey is it safe if a use a simple variable just before run it in the query? Like this $variable=$_GET['MyGet'] and the insert $variable in the query? is it safe to just change GET by POST (in case is a form)?

Comment: @Boris No, that’s no more safe. It doesn’t matter whether you use GET or POST, or whether you store it in a different variable. Whatever is stored in user input is potentially _very_ harmful. Just think what would happen if I opened `www.yoursite.com/updateimage.php?id=5; delete from articulos`. That’s what prepared statements avoid.

Answer (score -1):

what you were doing wrong is that you passed the old amount of telVisto as a string (telVisto='5'+1), and you can't add a number to a string. ;)

And also check that column name 'ID' is either capital letter or small letter.

Comment: In this is it `telVisto` = `telVisto` + 1   , `telVisto` Over here is column name , but column value can not use this way ofcourse, you have retrive current value of that particular coumn then add 1 to it and update your database, let me know if it works